# Как вернуть значение из промисса

Tags: javascript, promise

у меня есть такая функция:

```
a = fetch('handler/app.php', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text()
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response
    })
```

Как я могу вернуть из неё значение, а не промис? (получить в а)

Comment: никак,
надо a обернуть в асинхронную функцию и уже работать там со значением промиса

Comment: У вас тут нет функции.